# IMCE with Amazon S3

Tags: files, wysiwyg

I'm having an issue configuring IMCE to rely on the Amazon S3 bucket pointed to by the AmazonS3 module: https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3. I have successfully configured image fields to use the S3 bucket location, but the IMCE file browsing window appears blank after being clicked on from within the ckeditor window and when file browsing is enabled for image fields.

Has anyone successfully hooked this up, and if so, could you either direct me to or write detailed, step-by-step instructions for accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AmazonS3 7.x-1.x-dev version. It contains a fix for IMCE compatibility.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2204401

Comment: Seems straightforward. I'll test this tomorrow and see how it goes. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: This solution worked.